# Python program exiting after a success in a try: block

Tags: python

So I'm making a python program that would ping a host and see if that host has the port open. But after the first host is discovered, the program exits. I want the program to write all the hosts that have port 22 open to the alive_hosts.txt file. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

The hosts.txt file looks like this:

192.168.1.1

192.168.1.5

192.168.2.13

192.168.5.4

...

```
import socket

fp = open("hosts.txt", "r")
fp2 = open("alive_hosts.txt", "a")

Lines = fp.readlines()

for line in Lines:
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(0.37)
        result = s.connect_ex((line, 22))
        s.close()
        fp2.write(line + "\n")
        continue
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: What is the point of the `continue` at the end of the `for` loop?

Comment: can you comment out `continue`, its not necessary in the `try` part. You can replace `pass` with `continue` instead

Comment: if i comment out the continue and replace pass with continue the program still exits after the first host is written to the alive_hosts.txt file

Comment: Try to add ```print('connection failed)``` after ```except...:``` and remove ```pass```,See how many times it is getting printed

Comment: Hint: look carefully at the value of `line` (do something like `print("*" + line + "*")`). Is there anything there that shouldn't be?

Comment: its getting printed every time an ip from hosts.txt doesnt have the port 22 open

Comment: @TurePålsson its printing the ip addresses in hosts.txt but after each line is an empty space like a new line.
Console output:
192.168.1.1

192.168.1.5

192.168.2.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a file line by line, you get the trailing newline character on each line. This makes the hostname lookup fail, so you need to strip that away. Also, you do not need `readlines()`; you can iterate directly of the open file:

```
for line in fp:
    line = line[:-1]     # Strip trailing newline
    s = socket.socket(...)
```

I would also recommend trying to narrow down the `try:` block a bit. As the code looks now, you are, for example, handling write errors to the output file the same as a non-responsive host!

I would do something like

```
for line in fp:
    hostname = line[:-1] # Strip newline.

    # Use a resource manager block so that we don't have to
    # remember to close the socket.
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.settimeout(0.37)
        try:
            # Keep the code inside 'try' to a minimum.
            result = s.connect_ex((hostname, 22))
        except Exception as e:
            # print('Error:', e)
            # Something went wrong, skip rest of iteration.
            continue

    # If we get here, all went ok. Write to output file.
    fp2.write(hostname + "\n")
```

Answer (score -3):

Remove the 'continue' as instead of continuing the for loop, it is skipping over the for loop.